# Breaking change of IAspectProvider in PostSharp 3.0?

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

Today I upgraded to PostSharp 3. After some messing around with referencing the correct DLLs in my projects I compile and all seems fine, until I get a runtime exception. An aspect which has been working perfectly fine in PostSharp 2.1 now behaves differently.

It's a generic aspect applied with help of `IAspectProvider`. Full source [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework.Aspects/Windows/Aspects/ViewModel/ViewModelAttribute.cs).

```
public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects( object targetElement )
{
    Type targetType = (Type)targetElement;
    Type genericAspect = typeof( ViewModelAspect<,> ).MakeGenericType( _propertiesEnumType, _commandsEnumType );
    yield return new AspectInstance( targetType, Activator.CreateInstance( genericAspect ) as IAspect );
}
```

What seems to happen is the aspect with wrong generic parameters is applied to my type. When I use dotPeek to look at the post-compiled code I see a newly introduced generic field with generic parameters which are meant to be applied on a different type. **In fact, all types with the aspect applied to share the same generic parameters** (and thus only one is correct).

This was working correctly before, **did anything relating to `IAspectProvider` change in PostSharp 3 that I should think about?**

For debugging purposes I already checked whether `_propertiesEnumType` and `_commandsEnumType` are set correctly at build time, and they are, thus I think something must go wrong afterwards; perhaps the created aspects being applied to the wrong instances?

---

Below you can see the decompiled code where PostSharp seems to be doing something wrong. The correct aspect seems to be introduced, however the property I am introducing is exposed as a different (wrong) type. Notice the `ViewModel.Main` as parameter of the aspect, contrasted with the `ViewModel.ActivityOverview` as parameter for the `CommandFactory`, which should be `ViewModel.Main` as well.

```
[NonSerialized]
private ViewModelAspect<Laevo.ViewModel.Main.Binding.Properties, Laevo.ViewModel.Main.Binding.Commands> \u003C\u003Ez__aspect35;

private CommandFactory<Laevo.ViewModel.ActivityOverview.Binding.Commands> CommandFactory
{
  get
  {
    return ((ViewModelAspect<Laevo.ViewModel.ActivityOverview.Binding.Properties, Laevo.ViewModel.ActivityOverview.Binding.Commands>) this.\u003C\u003Ez__aspect35).CommandFactory;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to be a bug in the new version. [The updated version on NuGet fixes the issue.](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/1499-breaking-change-in-postsharp-3-iaspectprovider-with-generic-aspects)

---

Before the fix was released, I temporarily worked around it by introducing non-generic members instead and relying on reflection a bit more at run time.

```
[IntroduceMember( Visibility = Visibility.Private )]
//public CommandFactory<TCommands> CommandFactory
public object CommandFactory
{
    get { return _commandFactory; }
    private set { _commandFactory = value; }
}
```

Notice that the *incorrect* conversion (it should be `Laevo.ViewModel.Main` in this case) is still generated by PostSharp:

```
private object CommandFactory
{
  get
  {
    return ((ViewModelAspect<Laevo.ViewModel.ActivityOverview.Binding.Properties, Laevo.ViewModel.ActivityOverview.Binding.Commands>) this.\u003C\u003Ez__aspect35).CommandFactory;
  }
}
```

However, since the correct generic aspect *is created*, I can cast to the correct type at run time. Everything works ... the code just got a whole lot messier (and probably slower due to relying on reflection more).